# How to move "apply coupon code" block above the cart's total price with ajax in cart page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart, shopping-cart, coupon

Ajax is not working when I try to move the coupon block from cart.php to the cart-totals.php file.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_totals', 'custom_display_coupon_form_below_proceed_checkout', 25 );
 
function custom_display_coupon_form_below_proceed_checkout() {
   ?>
      <form class="woocommerce-coupon-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ); ?>" method="post">
         <?php if ( wc_coupons_enabled() ) { ?>
            <div class="coupon under-proceed">
               <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="input-text" id="coupon_code" value="" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Coupon code', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" style="width: 100%" />
               <button type="submit" class="button" name="apply_coupon" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" style="width: 100%"><?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
            </div>
         <?php } ?>
      </form>
   <?php
}
```

[image of cart page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YvxN.png)

the function is working to display the coupon field. And the coupon is applied successfully but the page getting refreshed. The Ajax is not working. Can anyone help me with the fix?

Comment: Your question is unclear, and if you don't provide your related code and explanations, nobody is going to be able to help you. So edit your question please.

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec, thank you for your suggestion. I have updated the question with more details. Thank you.